# Redirect logged in users if they are on a specific page

Tags: hooks, redirect, actions

I'm trying to prevent a user access besides the admin to the registeration page and reset password page if they are already logged in. I have the following:

```
function redirect_loggedin_users() {
// Maybe use is_user_logged_in() instead?
if (!current_user_can('manage_options') && is_page(array(2090, 2092))) {
    wp_redirect(home_url());
            exit();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'redirect_loggedin_users');
```

I tested it and it's not working. Can someone please assist me? Thanks.

Comment: check error logs, but `wp_redirect()` will usually only work if headers haven't been sent yet, so has to happen before `get_header()`. Actually that seems like legit hook cause it's before headers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem is that you're hooking in too early. Reference the [Hooks API Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). Template conditionals such as `is_page()` are only available after the query has been set up and parsed. The earliest action that you can usually safely rely on query conditionals is `pre_get_posts`. You're hooking into `init`, which fires much earlier:

- `muplugins_loaded`   After must-use plugins are loaded
- `registered_taxonomy`    For category, post_tag, etc.
- `registered_post_type`   For post, page, etc.
- `plugins_loaded` After active plugins and pluggable functions are loaded
- `sanitize_comment_cookies`
- `setup_theme`
- `load_textdomain`    For the default domain
- `after_setup_theme`  Generally used to initialize theme settings/options.
- `auth_cookie_malformed`
- `auth_cookie_valid`
- `set_current_user`
- **`init`**   **Typically used by plugins to initialize. The current user is already authenticated by this time.**
- `widgets_init`   Used to register sidebars. This is fired at 'init', with a priority of 1.
- `register_sidebar`   For each sidebar and footer area
- `wp_register_sidebar_widget` For each widget
- `wp_default_scripts` (ref array)
- `wp_default_styles`  (ref array)
- `admin_bar_init`
- `add_admin_bar_menus`
- `wp_loaded`  After WordPress is fully loaded
- **`parse_request`**  **Allows manipulation of HTTP request handling (ref array)**
- `send_headers`   Allows customization of HTTP headers (ref array)
- **`parse_query`**    (ref array)
- **`pre_get_posts`**  **Exposes the query-variables object before a query is executed. (ref array)**
- `posts_selection`
- `wp` After WP object is set up (ref array)
- **`template_redirect`**
- `get_header`
- `wp_enqueue_scripts`

Given the nature of what you're trying to do, I would recommend hooking into **`template_redirect`**.

Comment: You're right! I am firing it too quickly. Thanks for the heads up and I'll definitely give it a try and report back my results. Thank you.

Comment: Update: It works great!